# MATLAB Coder converting from classes of MATLAB to C/C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

MATLAB contains several classdef with properties and methods.  In converting to C/C++ from MATLAB through MATLAB Coder,  Coder gives error message “All entry-point files must be fun functions.  ABC.m is a class”.

Should I rewrite the classes in classdef into separate methods? Are there better approaches for converting from classes of MATLAB to C/C++?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/how-working-with-matlab-classes-is-different-for-code-generation.html)?

Comment: Classes cannot be passed directly to `codegen` or added as entry-points in the Coder App. Instead, write a function which uses your class(es) and use that function as your entry-point.